# Django how to iterate through a list of objects in a view?

Tags: python, django

So I have a view that asks the user for input and I cannot figure out what to do to somehow iterate through the list and get the user input on all the objects...

```
def get(self, request, language, word):
    '''Get reqeust to edit taken in steps'''
    context = cache.get(word)
    form_class = DefinitionInfoForm
    context['form_class'] = form_class
    return render(request, 
        'study/add_info.html',
        context_instance=RequestContext(request, context))
```

Here is my get that is inside a CBV. I have loaded a cache of objects and I would like to somehow iterate through them one at a time making a new `get` for every one if possible

OR

do a bulk ad and render them all with forms and modify all the objects in the post method

I am using this form to add the info and I can not figure out how to do it with a bulk  or one at a time...

```
class DefinitionInfoForm(forms.Form):

    part_of_speech = forms.CharField(required=True, label=_(u'Part of Speech'))
    pronunciation = forms.CharField(required=True, label=_(u'Pronunciation'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the answer for me was to use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets and add a queryset as an argument.

I could then pass it to the template as context and iterate through the formset there